# inline-block does not stack my "blocks"

Tags: css

I'm trying to stack these "blocks" with some margins between them. The problem is that they do not "block" with 3 pixels of space between them. They just stacks at top of each other (typical div tags).

```
<div style="display: inline-block; margin: 3px; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
</div>​
```

Why does it not work? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/Y9gCG/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a stylesheet.

Other thant that,
The `inline-block` and other css statements must be on the children divs :

```
<div>
    <div style="margin: 3px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 3px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 3px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
    <div style="margin: 3px; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
</div>​
```

with a stylesheet : *

CSS

```
.child{
    margin: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer is working like a charm ^^ I'll accept it when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the margin on the inner divs, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle showing how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9gCG/3/

```
div.container div {
 margin-bottom:3px;
 background-color: #000;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the margin and inline-block property to the parent element instead of the children, change the code to this :

```
<div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 3px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 3px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 3px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #000000; height: 100px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; margin: 3px;"></div>
</div>​
```

and it should work.